# Symfony 2.8.2 flashmessage and redirecttoroute

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.8.2 and somehow the FlashMessage does not live through a redirect.

```
$this->addFlash('success', 'Expedition erfolgreich!');
return $this->redirectToRoute('mainmenu_dashboard');
```

After the redirect there is no flashmessage. I already looked in the session (dumped it) but there is no flash message after the redirect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a base Twig template that loops through your flash messages and displays them?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check for, and display, the flashMessage in your twig template for the `mainmenu_dashboard` route.

For example:

```
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('success') %}
    <div class="success">{{ flashMessage }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The flash will exist in session, between routes, until they are used.

[Symfony Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for your answer!

I discovered the problem somewhere else. I used session_write_close() somewhere else to set the session to not blocking (to be able to cancel a request). This was the reason why session was not writeable at this point anymore!

Comment: just to possibly help out. You shouldnt be calling session_write_close directly. call `Session::save()` instead on the session object.  It [will close it for you](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#method_save) automatically.